bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73: Bad file descriptor
I am trying to run a Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code via a Poetry virtual environment. I keep getting the following error when running any cell:
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73). 
View Jupyter log for further details.

When clicking on the Jupyer log I can see:
16:42:48.465 [info] Starting Kernel (Python Path: ~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe, Poetry, 3.12.4) for '~\Documents\icp_matching\TEST_NOTEBOOK.ipynb' (disableUI=false)
16:42:49.503 [info] Process Execution: ~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.__version__); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.__file__)"
16:42:49.525 [info] Process Execution: ~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --f=c:\Users\~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-17844hBCgbswlg1Du.json
    > cwd: ~\Documents\icp_matching
16:42:53.185 [error] Disposing kernel process due to an error Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0e018db9046349855e2f8251c00f6ac498be9fc804ffa85c69bae59b1b82b8875.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher
    > Interpreter Id = c:\USERS\~\APPDATA\LOCAL\PYPOETRY\CACHE\VIRTUALENVS\ICP-MATCHING-Z1RYMIKI-PY3.12\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:309:44339)
    > stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)
16:42:53.187 [error] Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
16:42:53.188 [error] Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
16:42:53.189 [warn] Failed to shutdown kernel, .jvsc74a57bd0e018db9046349855e2f8251c00f6ac498be9fc804ffa85c69bae59b1b82b8875.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispose')
    at DT.shutdown (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:314:13629)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async _T.shutdown (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:314:22107)]
16:42:53.190 [warn] Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0e018db9046349855e2f8251c00f6ac498be9fc804ffa85c69bae59b1b82b8875.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher
    > Interpreter Id = c:\USERS\~\APPDATA\LOCAL\PYPOETRY\CACHE\VIRTUALENVS\ICP-MATCHING-Z1RYMIKI-PY3.12\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:309:44339)
    > stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)
16:42:53.191 [warn] Kernel Error, context = start Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0e018db9046349855e2f8251c00f6ac498be9fc804ffa85c69bae59b1b82b8875.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher
    > Interpreter Id = c:\USERS\~\APPDATA\LOCAL\PYPOETRY\CACHE\VIRTUALENVS\ICP-MATCHING-Z1RYMIKI-PY3.12\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:309:44339)
    > stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)
16:42:53.211 [info] Process Execution: ~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
16:42:54.218 [info] Dispose Kernel '~\Documents\icp_matching\TEST_NOTEBOOK.ipynb' associated with '~\Documents\icp_matching\TEST_NOTEBOOK.ipynb'
16:42:54.219 [error] Error in execution Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0e018db9046349855e2f8251c00f6ac498be9fc804ffa85c69bae59b1b82b8875.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher
    > Interpreter Id = c:\USERS\~\APPDATA\LOCAL\PYPOETRY\CACHE\VIRTUALENVS\ICP-MATCHING-Z1RYMIKI-PY3.12\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:309:44339)
    > stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)
16:42:54.220 [error] Error in execution (get message for cell) Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0e018db9046349855e2f8251c00f6ac498be9fc804ffa85c69bae59b1b82b8875.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher
    > Interpreter Id = c:\USERS\~\APPDATA\LOCAL\PYPOETRY\CACHE\VIRTUALENVS\ICP-MATCHING-Z1RYMIKI-PY3.12\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:309:44339)
    > stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)
16:42:54.228 [info] Process Execution: ~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\icp-matching-Z1rYmikI-py3.12\Scripts\python.exe -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"

None of the answers here are helping - I have even added pyzmq explicitly to my poetry file, and the jupyter and ipykernel packages are both in the file. Running poetry install gives me no issues, and I can run .py files that import the packages perfectly fine. Switching to the pre-release version of the VS Code Jupyter extension also does not work.
What do I do?

It could be on how Python installation issue. How did you install Python?

Because the error message refers to C++ file, not Python file, the error is likely related to the installation of native libraries.

@PraysonW.Daniel From Windows Store

We just need to install Python differently. You can use pyenv + poetry.


Bad file descriptor
(C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkywtyyea\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73).

Hi, according to this issue on github. This may be caused by ipykernel or libzmq not being installed correctly.
You could try to reinstall libzmq and ipykernel package.

Do you mean pyzmq not libzmq? And poetry remove pyzmq ipykernel followed by poetry add pyzmq ipykernel is giving me the same issue as before
